# bitbucket file commit always goes to root folder

Tags: bitbucket, git-commit

I do a `git add`, then `git commit`, then `git push origin` of a file from `my-dir/x/`. Yet each commit always winds up in bitbucket.com's root folder `my-dir/` (it does not wind up in `my-dir/x/` folder).

I tried:

```
git add file.php
git add file.php my-dir/x/file1.php
git add file.php /my-dir/x/file1.php
git add file.php ./my-dir/x/file1.php
```

What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: What do you think `git add file.php my-dir/x/file1.php` does?

Comment: i think all it does is add the file from that location; ergo basically nothing - but i saw someone suggest it; i tried it, but i think it's redundant. thanks for responding; but do you understand my question and have an idea of how to get the file into the proper target location on bitbucket?

Comment: Does a file exist at `my-dir/x/file1.php`? Are you trying to commit `file.php` at that location?

Comment: in one case there is a preexisting file[same name] in bitbucket.com in repo name [my-dir]/x/file.php; and i am trying to commit local file1.php from a git init'd folder  ... i start the cmd prompt [it shows i am in c:\work\repos\my-dir\x], i add the file [then commit and push].... then on bitbucket.org, the file appears in the repo name [my-dir], not in my-dir/x. so it's making it to the my-dir, but not the proper subfolder. 

thx for helping; do you think something was done wrong on my end? otherwise, you'd say, "oh you were just supposed to do such and such." :}.

another file, i created

Comment: "the file appears in the repo name [my-dir], not in my-dir/x. so it's making it to the my-dir, but not the proper subfolder". I'm still not entirely clear what you're trying to do. But the file structure of your local copy should match the file structure in your repository. Is your local repository created in `my-dir` or in `my-dir\x`?

Comment: thx, i hope to be clear... trying to commit file1.php from local, to bitbucket. local file.php is here: C:\Data1\DEVELOPMENT\company\REPOS\appname\ncfiles\activity\file.php.  using git add file1.php, git commit -m "msg" file1.php, and git push origin. the file lands in bitbucket here: https://bitbucket.org/company/appname. see how i am in the folder appname\ncfiles\activity when i commit the file; yet it lands in bitbucket: only in folder appname, not further in .../appname/ncfiles/activity folder. and yes, the path exists locally, and in the bitbucket folder structure. better? thx again!

Comment: Looking at `C:\Data1\DEVELOPMENT\company\REPOS\appname\ncfiles\activity\‌​file.php`, in which directory is your local Git repository? I'm guessing it's in `activity\ `?

Comment: YES. and when I that local dir [activity]... I try "git push origin" it normally makes it only to remote "appname" dir. now after needing to reset pw for bitbucket.org, cannot push anything, getting permission denied. have to figure that out all over again. hate to say this git is humbling and maddening. seems very unsimple at this pt. thx for any advice.

Comment: wow back to square 1. did a [1]ssh-keygen, [2]pasted new .pub into my bitbucket.org, [3]now a git push origin gives same msg: Permission denied(publickey)...could not read from remote repo. make sure you have correct access rights and repo exists. then [4]did a "ssh -T git@bitbucket.org" and it says "logged in as yourusername. you can use git or hg to connect to bitbucket. shell access is disabled." I have never found yet a simple.step-by-step here is exactly what to do - and have it work. is bitbucket like a dark art where ppl learn to poke around and kind of make it work well?

Comment: to whomever this may help - [a]I reset my bitbucket.org password. [b]now my bash as usual can "add", "commit" a file, but not push. error is Permission denied(publickey). steps that got "push" working [not completely to correct target folder, but at least to remote repo]: [1]ssh-keygen ==> then copy key info and paste into bitbucket account SSH section, [2]git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:myaccountname/appname.git [3]git push origin ==> "first integrate changes... do a 'git pull'" [4]git pull ==> then add comment into file [5]git pull ==> works. [6]git push origin ==> to root folder